# Fb.ui send on mobile alternative or workaround

Tags: mobile, send, fb.ui

I am using the send dialog from Fb.ui. On Desktop this works fine, but the method doesn't have mobile support. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog

It will always end in an API error code 4202: This dialog is not available on this device.

With a little research I found the send-button as an alternative. But this is no longer supported. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/send-button/

Has anyone another alternative or a workaround?